# Wrong area using Albers Equal Area Projection in GRASS for Java, Indonesia

Tags: coordinate-system, grass-gis, area

I am just getting to know GRASS 7.0 and I am struggling finding a good projection to work on a spatial analysis of Java, Indonesia. I am new to the forum, so if information's are missing for a better understanding of the problem please let me know. I built my own projection using the Albers Equal Area Projection (which is similar to http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/asia-south-albers-equal-area-conic/ only the central meridian and the standard parallels are changed):

```json
["Java Equal Area Conic",

GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",  DATUM["D_WGS_1984",         
SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],  
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],     UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Albers"], PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0], PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",110.0],
PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",-6.38],
PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",-8.3],
PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",-0.0], UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

I checked if the projection works by letting GRASS calculate the area of the Java Island. The "Query results" show Sq_Meters=10.371, but it should be around 128.297 km², though.

Is some conversion not working? Is the projection file wrong? How can I let GRASS calculate the actual area of the Java Island in meters? Or is this simply not possible with Albers?

Comment: What projection does your data originally have, and how did you change it to your custom CRS?

Comment: The original data has a projection (.prj file) defined as: GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]. Setting up a Location in GRASS I set the projection as shown above using the GUI of GRASS 7.0. Every file I load into the Mapset of the Location will be re-projected to my custom Albers projection.

Comment: I'm not sure how GRASS does it, but reprojecting and assigning a new projection are two different things. Can you use ogr2ogr or gdalwarp to reproject the file outside GRASS?

Comment: When you load data into GRASS, use r.import and v.import to automatically reproject the data (available in GRASS 7.0.3).

Comment: I installed GRASS 7.0.3 and imported the data with v.import and also using v.in.ogr. Both works now! So I guess it was a bug in GRASS 7.0.1

Comment: Please consider to copy your solution as an answer to this question...

Comment: I first used r.to.gdal and I thought that the raster map will be directly reprojected to the projection of the location, which was wrong. I needed to use r.import of GRASS 7.0.3, which did the trick, like @Anna said.